# Convert String to Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like the following

```
'{"type": "line","data": {"labels": [],"datasets": [{"fill": false,"data": [],"borderWidth": 1,"pointRadius": 2,"pointBorderColor": "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)","pointBackgroundColor": "rgba(52, 162, 235, 0.2)"}]},"options": {"tooltips": {"displayColors": false},"legend": {"display": false},"title": {"display": true,"text": "Unemployment Rate"},"scales": {"yAxes": [{"ticks": {"callback": function(e, t) {return 0 == t ? e + "%" : t % 2 == 0 ? e : null},"beginAtZero": true,"drawTicks": false}}],"xAxes": [{"gridLines": {"drawOnChartArea": false},"type": "time","time": {"displayFormats": {"year": "YYYY"}}}]}}};'
```

You will notice that options.scales.yAxes.ticks.callback is a function. How can I convert this string to usable javascript? I want to use it as a Javascript object. JSON.parse doesn't work as it's not valid JSON.

Comment: You *can* use the `eval` function. I'd seriously advise against it though, especially if you're getting this data from someone else.

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'` when trying to eval it. Also I know it will be safe.

Comment: well it is not JSON because it contains a function.

Comment: I know I said it's not JSON. I want to get it from a string to a Javascript Object. If I type it out as Javascript it works but I can't get the conversion to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is not JSON since it is not valid JSON. You can use new Function, but eval is not a great idea.

```js
var str = '{"type": "line","data": {"labels": [],"datasets": [{"fill": false,"data": [],"borderWidth": 1,"pointRadius": 2,"pointBorderColor": "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)","pointBackgroundColor": "rgba(52, 162, 235, 0.2)"}]},"options": {"tooltips": {"displayColors": false},"legend": {"display": false},"title": {"display": true,"text": "Unemployment Rate"},"scales": {"yAxes": [{"ticks": {"callback": function(e, t) {return 0 == t ? e + "%" : t % 2 == 0 ? e : null},"beginAtZero": true,"drawTicks": false}}],"xAxes": [{"gridLines": {"drawOnChartArea": false},"type": "time","time": {"displayFormats": {"year": "YYYY"}}}]}}};'

var data = (new Function ('return ' + str))()
console.log(data)
```

Comment: can you please explain whats happening in second line ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function